# Tuples and Multiple Quantifiers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

[image]

So I'm familiar with predicate logic and the usage of nested quantifiers. However, I've never seen anything like this before. How would I even go about reading this? Also, I don't understand the indexing for x at all

Comment: It is simply a matrix defining the relation $\text {Loves}(x,y)$ in a finite universe.

Comment: Well I understand that, but I've never seen anything like the long list of quantifiers shown on the second last line

Comment: We assume that we have 4+4 individuals (all distinct) and thus 16 possibility, out of which 9 are "true", i.e. using the table row => columns we have that 1 Loves 2 and 1 Loves 3 and so on, that means: $\text {Loves} = \{ (1,2), (1,3), (2,3), (3,3), \ldots \}$

Comment: Okay I see. So now applying the quantifiers to the possibilities; say for x1, it's the case that x1 love some other x in the set. And for x4, it's the case that x4 loves all x in the set?

Comment: It's unclear what the formula $\alpha$ is, and what the variables $x_i$ are. Show the remainder of the question?

Comment: Unfortunately that's the entire question defined. the rest of the question is asking properties of the given such as "how many tuples can be inputs to the relation <alpha>", etc.

Comment: To answer your other question: $x_1,x,2,\ldots,x_{37}$ are just different variables, just as $x,y,z$ are different variables. Indexing is useful when there are too many variables and there aren't enough letters to distinguish them using (or when we prefer to label them kinda numerically). Do you have any other question re: this one? If not, consider  deleting this Question? To notify someone of your new message, put @Ryan or somesuch anywhere in your comment.